# Python module not producing logs after being imported

Tags: python, logging

I am building a tool with the following file structure:

```
+- my_tool
|   +- logs_dir
|   +- my_package
|   |   +- __init__.py  # main __init__
|   |   +- classes
|   |   |   +- __init__.py  # empty __init__
|   |   |   +- my_class.py
|   |   +- util
|   |   |   +- __init__.py  # empty __init__
|   |   |   +- _logger.py
|   |   +- tests
|   |   |   +- __init.py__  # empty __init__
|   |   |   +- test_my_class.py
|   |   +- config
|   |   |   +- logger.json
+- my_script.py
```

The python scripts contain the following code:

main `__init__.py`

```
from my_package.util import _logger
```

`my_class.py`

```
import logging

class TheClass():

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.log.info('this is a log output!')
    
    def a_method(self):
        return 'a string that is returned...'
```

`_logger.py`

```
import logging
import logging.config
from pathlib import Path
import json

logging_config_path = Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'config/logger.json'
with open(logging_config_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as config_file:
    LOGGING_CONFIG = json.load(config_file)
    
log_path = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent

log_file = LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['file']['filename']
LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['file']['filename'] = log_path.join_path(log_file)

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
```

`test_my_class.py`

```
import pytest
from my_package.classes.my_class import TheClass

def test_the_class():
    the_class = TheClass()
    assert the_class.a_method() == 'a string that is returned...'
```

`my_script.py`

```
from my_tool.my_package.classes.my_class import TheClass

the_class = TheClass()
print(the_class.a_method())
```

`logger.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "standard": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)|%(lineno)d:: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "formatter": "standard",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "file": {
            "formatter": "standard",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs_dir/log.log"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": false
        },
        "my_package": {
            "handlers": ["default", "file"],
            "level": "DEBUG", 
            "propagate": false
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `test_my_class.py`, I get logs in both the terminal and the `log_dir` directory. However, when I run `my_script.py`, no logs are produced at all.

I have tried changing `"disable_existing_loggers"` in the `logger.json` file but that does not change the behaviour.

How do I get the logs to output properly when I run `my_script.py`? Why is it currently not producing an output.

Answer (score 0):

You do your logging setup in `_logger.py`.

When your run `my_script.py` the `_logger.py` is not executed. Because of that python's default settings for logging are relevant.

The default log-level is `logging.WARNING`. This means that `logging.info()` is lower then the default level not outputed somewhere.

Comment: Ok. Couple of questions (to make sure I have the correct understanding). Why is `_logger.py` not run when its in the package top level `__init__.py`? I thought that would make it run every time. Why does it work when I perform the unit tests with pytest? How to I ensure `_logger.py` gets run every time, regardless of which part of my package is imported (here I only have `my_class.py`, but in reality I have 5 or 6 modules at the same level as `my_class.py`)?

Comment: You run not the module `my_class` but only the script `my_class.py`. Sorry, but your questions are to complex and to much. Please break them down to simple atomar questions with minimal working example and open new questions for them.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried to rephrase the question to ask how to run the `_logger.py` function when any part of the module is imported here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213894/always-run-python-logger-setup-script-when-other-module-parts-are-imported